# How to get the Jinja2 generated input value data?

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

In my HTML file, I have:

```
  <table>
      {% for user in user_data_html %}
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value='{{ user.FirstName }}' />  
         </td>
         <td>
             <input name="submit" type="submit" value='update' />
         </td>
     </tr>
     {% else %}
     <tr><td>no user found</td></tr>
     {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

I want to modify the user name in the webpage by clicking update button in each row. But I always get the first "firstname" using the following python code in the backend:

```
firstname = request.form['firstname']
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forms get confused when you use the same name for each input name.  You could either create a separate form around each table cell with the first name or you can use the jinja2 loop index to create unique input names...

```
<input id="firstname{{ loop.index }}" name="firstname{{ loop.index }}" type="text" value='{{ user.FirstName }}' />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`request.form` is a [`werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict).  You can get out all the values for a field with its [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method:

```
a_firstname = request.form['firstname']
all_firstnames = request.form.getlist('firstname')
```

If you need the names to be in the order they were defined in the form you need to subclass `flask.Request` and set its [`parameter_storage_class`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.parameter_storage_class) to an instance of [`ImmutableOrderedMultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableOrderedMultiDict).  Then you need to set the [`request_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.request_class) field on your `Flask` instance:

```
from flask import Flask, Request
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableOrderedMultiDict

class OrderedRequest(Request):
    parameter_storage_class = ImmutableOrderedMultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.request_class = OrderedRequest
```

Then `request.form.getlist('firstname')` will return the fields in the order the browser sent them (which is conventionally in the order they are defined in the HTML).